# Write a function that takes in a file name and a single letter as input and RETURNS True if a player has a last name beginning with that character

Tags: python, csv

"Write a function that playerHasLastInitial(filename, char) that takes in a file name and a single letter as input 
and RETURNS True if a player on the roster has a last name beginning with that character, otherwise False.
We want to avoid loading the whole file into memory, so use a while loop and the file readline() method, NOT the readlines() or read() methods"

I need to use a while loop, and I can't use dict.

So the names in the first column are first and last, so when I try and split them into two separate items, I get "IndexError: string index out of range"

```
def playerHasLastInitial(filename, char):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    while True:
        lines = f.readline()
        for v in lines:
            name = v.split(" ")[0]
            lastName = name[1]

            if char in lastName:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

So I should have:

> playerHasLastInitial('C:\Users\wpqx1\Documents\hw5\cubsRoster.csv',
>   'A') True

I get `"IndexError: string index out of range"`

Comment: Three columns:"Name    Age   Country Code" The names are listed Alberto Almora, Javier Baez etc. So I need to split that category.

Comment: Name Age CountryCode
Jim Adduci 34 CA
Albert Almora 25 US
Adbert Alzolay 24 VE
Javier Baez 26 PR
Tony Barnette 35 US
David Bote 26 US
Brad Brach 33 US
Kris Bryant 27 US
Victor Caratini 25 PR
Nicholas Castellanos 27 US
Xavier Cedeno 32 PR
Tyler Chatwood 29 US
Steve Cishek 33 US
Tim Collins 29 US

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
lines = f.readline()
```

You get only 1 line. So when you do next:

```
for v in lines:
```

`lines` is 1 long string, so `v` is just 1 char at a time, so `name` is also 1 char. So when you do next:

```
lastName = name[1]
```

You get an error, as `name` doesn't have index "1", but only "0" index.

You need to drop the loop, and do:

```
name = lines.split(" ")[0]
```

And recommanded to change some names of variables (for example `line` instead of `lines`, as it is just 1 line at a time)